# What's the term for "the supremum of constants $\alpha$ such that a function is $\alpha$-Hölder continuous"?

Tags: terminology, holder-spaces

The $\alpha$-Hölder norm of a function $f(x)\colon I \to X$ where $I=[0,T]$ and $X$ is some Banach space with norm $\|\cdot\|$ is:

$$\|f(t)\|_{\alpha}\colon=\sup_{s \neq t \in I}\frac{\|f(t)-f(s)\|}{|t-s|^{\alpha}}$$

If $\|f(x)\|_{\alpha}<\infty$ we say $f(x)$ is $\alpha$-Hölder continuous. What is interesting is that if $f(x)$ is $\alpha$-Hölder continuous, then it is $\beta$-Hölder continuous for $0<\beta<\alpha$. Hölder continuity is integral in understanding how rough a function is. If a function is $1$-Hölder continuous, it is Lipschitz and thus a.e. differentiable. If a function is $1+\epsilon$-Hölder continuous it is constant.

Because of these things and other technical considerations we are interested in the quantity:

$$\sup\{\alpha>0 \colon \|f(x)\|_{\alpha} <\infty\}$$

My question is simple, is there a name for this quantity? I often use "the Hölder norm is $\frac{1}{2}$" for example but this is not quite right even if it is understood in context.

Comment: Do you mean the _(Hölder) exponent_, see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition)?

Comment: @mickep Hölder exponent just means $\alpha$, I want to know what the supremum is called.

Comment: @mickep I want to find the supremum of Hölder exponents such that a function is that exponent Hölder continuous.

Comment: Thank you for clearifying (for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sometimes referred to as **Hölder exponent**, see for example the abstract in [this](http://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:377071/FULLTEXT01.pdf) paper.

This terminology is also used in [Signal and Image Multiresolution Analysis](https://books.google.com/books?id=AtYpdpIgnisC&pg=SA2-PA1&lpg=SA2-PA1&dq=supremum%20holder%20exponent&source=bl&ots=YY_cRQ7ljh&sig=H9DJdEKKy8zdYJUmM4FrfPYXHPM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCwQ6AEwA2oVChMIjaDy2p7AxwIVSBY-Ch3scwV9#v=onepage&q=supremum%20holder%20exponent&f=false).

---

I would use this terminology with caution since on the Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition), for example, it appears that if $f$ is Hölder continuous with parameter $\alpha$, then $\alpha$ is **a** Hölder exponent for $f$. (there is no mention of the maximality of $\alpha$.)

Also, all the problems I have encountered where phrased in the following way:

- *prove that $f$ is Hölder continuous for $\alpha < \beta$*,

instead of

- *prove that $\beta$ is the XXX for $f$.*

So even if there is an established name for it you are not the only one unaware of it.